# Closed Form for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, functional-equations

I am looking to find a closed form for
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2^n}$$
$f$ exists on $|x|<1$ and we can immediately see that $f$ satisfies the functional equation
$$f(x^2)=f(x)-x$$
Thus we only need to know $f$ on either $(-1, 0]$ or $[0,1)$. I really don't know how to proceed from here though. I would have thought this closed form was already known since it's so close to a geometric series, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: I don't think there is a closed form, at least in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: This is a quintessential example of lacunary functions. And this is the least property you can expect from elementary functions. I am certain that this cannot be written in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: You also have $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f\left(x^{2k-1}\right)=\frac{x}{1-x}$.

Comment: By Möbius inversion $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(2n-1) \frac{x^{2n-1}}{1-x^{2n-1}}$. @ThomasAndrews There is also $\frac{1}{1-x} = \prod_{k=0}^\infty (1+x^{2^k})$

Comment: Probably not very useful but $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2^n}=x+(1-x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lfloor \log_{2} n \rfloor x^n$